# Install Ubuntu 20.04 on separate HDD

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, hard-drive

I am running Windows 10 on new M.2 SSD and on the HDD I have some data (pics, docs, games etc) and I want to boot Ubuntu on it, but I don't want to lose the data. Previously I was trying to install PopOS but I failed due to hardware error. (I don't know what happened I tried everything). So my question now is what partitions do I need to make (BIOS Boot partition? boot/root/home/swap..) I know that root is must be.
Does the position of the partitions affect something about the booting the OS?

[image]

My data is on D, and G is something like archive, if needed I can move the few files back in D. I plan to install Ubuntu on the 343GB partition. The other two are some partitions I tried to work with when trying to install PopOS.

All in all, does the position of the partitions affect on something?

Thanks!

Comment: select `something else` when installing, make the 343GB partition "/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it ubuntu yet installed in your sistem?

If not:

You can divide the disk in FileSystem with your data and merge all the "useless" partition.

After that in the BIOS start the installer of linux and when the installer is in Section called "Installation type" select option "something else"

You choose the free space merged on windows. You can create the partition with "/" (root) mount point FileSystem ext4 and the second part is a ext4 "/home", if your system is modern you can't create the swap area.

Comment: Here is the thing, and I am very very very dissapointed... I installed Ubuntu, just before 5min. and it said to reboot, or my saved documents wont be saved, so i rebooted. My hdd is set to first boot device, but i booted into windows 10. When i oppened this pc, both the root and home partitions were empty and ntfs, despite i changed them to ext4 during the installation

Comment: The installation was successful, but I dont know what happened after the reboot...

Comment: Now after few minutes, I open this pc again and the two partitions arent recognised, I mean they have no letter

Comment: I will try again tomorrow, at the moment I am very angry, but, should I boot into legacy or UEFI mode..?This time I was in legacy mode and boot legacy first (if that has to do something with the problem..)

Comment: Only boot in UEFI boot mode, legacy will greatly confuse things. You cannot install Ubuntu to NTFS partitions. Use ext4 and only Something Else. Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? And if you did not turn Windows fast start up which sets hibernation flag, Windows restored to previous.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi